# Track cursor hover position and show hide menu similar to OSX dock / Windows start bar

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome

How do I achieve this effect using jQuery HTML and CSS - http://www.teehanlax.com/about/.
See how you can simply hover on the top of the site and the menu will automatically dropdown, similar to OSX's effect for the dock and the windows auto-show/hide start bar.

**UPDATE:**

Clarification. I am referring to the effect that when you are in the middle of the site and you move your mouse cursor towards the top of the viewport, the nav automatically slides down. You don't need to scroll, I believe it is detecting the location of your cursor with regards to the viewport.

**UPDATE2:**

Unfortunately it is still not completely working for me. :( I would like to recreate the same effects as teehanlax.com/about with these set of features:

1. hide nav when scroll down/ show nav when scroll up
2. show nav when mouseover top of viewport
3. change from static to fixed nav when scroll reaches offset height.

The tricky part is instead of using a `position:absolute` nav from the getgo, I am using a static nav that actually takes up height so I have to account for that. Also, when the screen width < 768px, the nav becomes a toggle menu, the mouse hover effect has to take into account of menu's full height.

It seems that right now on Safari everything is working except when you try to mouseout I can't get it to function properly. However, in Chrome on my Mac, it seems like the mouse hovering event is not triggering correctly - the nav seems to open and close right away. Also when in mobile view (width < 768px) I am experiencing ghosting issues of the nav. Not sure what is the cause of this..

Here's my best implementation live - **http://alchuang.com/indexnav.html** and the following are the respective JS for the 3 features. How do I combine the 3 features so that they play well with one another and function on both Chrome and Safari?

**1. JS for hiding/showing nav when scroll down/up:**

```
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 10;
var navbarHeight =  $('.navbar').height();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    var classin = $('.navbar-collapse').hasClass("in");
    // Make sure they scroll more than delta
    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;

    // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-show.
    // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight && !classin){
        // Scroll Down
            $('.navbar').removeClass('nav-show').addClass('nav-hidden');              
            $('.navbar-collapse').removeClass("in");
    } else {
        // Scroll Up
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height() && !classin) {          
                $('.navbar').removeClass('nav-hidden').addClass('nav-show');
                $('.navbar-collapse').removeClass("in");
        }
    }

    lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

**2. JS for mouse hovering show/hide**

```
$(function() {
    var mouseY = 0;
    var navbarHeight = $(".navbar").outerHeight();
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    mouseY = e.clientY || e.pageY;
    if(mouseY < navbarHeight) {
       $('.navbar').removeClass('nav-hidden').addClass('nav-show');
    }
}, false);

$('.navbar').mouseout(function() {
  if($(window).scrollTop() > navbarHeight) {
     $('.navbar').removeClass('nav-show').addClass('nav-hidden');
  }
});
```

**3. JS for changing from static to fixed nav (addNavMargin to offset the height of the static nav)**

```
var scroll_start = 0;
var startchange = $('section#passion');
var offset = startchange.offset();
if (startchange.length){
   $(document).scroll(function() { 
      scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
      if(scroll_start > offset.top) {
          $("section#viewer").addClass('addNavMargin');
          $(".navbar-default").addClass('navbar-hover');
       } else if (scroll_start == 0) {
          $("section#viewer").removeClass('addNavMargin');
          $(".navbar-default").removeClass('navbar-hover');

       }
   });
}          
});
```

Comment: When I hover on the top of the site nothing drops down just menu change opacity and another story is when I click on menu, then it drops down. My question is what do you need from teehanlax.com? Drop down menu or showing menu on scroll up/down?

Comment: Hello, perhaps I should clarify my question. I am referring to the effect that when you are in the middle of the site (you have to scroll pass a certain point until the nav disappears) and you move your mouse cursor towards the top of the viewport, the nav automatically slides down. You don't need to scroll, I believe it is detecting the location of your cursor with regards to the viewport.

Comment: Ok I see it now. There are many ways and yes one of them is locating the mouse position another would be transparent fixed element which triggers when the page is scrolled.

Comment: @mdesdev Hi Thanks for getting back to me.. unfortunately.. i've been scratching my head for the whole day trying to get everything working properly. I've updated my question with details and code. I am looking to implement these set of features: 1. hide nav when scroll down/ show nav when scroll up 2. show nav when mouseover top of viewport 3. change from static to fixed nav when scroll reaches offset height. I rewrote the page twice from scratch trying to iron out the issue on my own but still running into issues especially with Chrome. Can you provide any insights? Many many thanks!

Comment: Have you look at my updated answer? I provide all these functions in updated version of my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick example, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/np4hZ/)

```
<nav>
  <ul>
     <li>Link</li>
     <li>Link</li>
     <li>Link</li>
     <li>Link</li>
     <li>Link</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

---

```
nav {
  background: violet;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;

  transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 10px;
  color: #333;
}
```

---

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    var mouseY = 0;

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
      mouseY = e.clientY || e.pageY;
      if(mouseY < 70) {
         $('nav').css({ top: '0' });
      }
    }, false);

    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var sc = ($(this).scrollTop() > 70) ? $('nav').css({ top: '-70px' }) : $('nav').css({ top: '0' });
    });

    $('nav').mouseout(function() {
      if($(window).scrollTop() > 70) {
         $('nav').css({ top: '-70px' });
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

**Update:** Added show/hide on scroll.

Comment: Hi @mdesdev I am trying to implement this feature along with the hide when scroll feature, but they interfere with each other causing it to open/close when scrolled. Is there a way to detect cursor when not scrolling?

Comment: I've updated my answer with show/hide function on scroll also added mouseout function to `nav` to preserve previous functionality.

Answer (score 0):

you can user this script / tutorial
https://medium.com/@mariusc23/hide-header-on-scroll-down-show-on-scroll-up-67bbaae9a78c

Comment: Hello, perhaps I should clarify my question. I am referring to the effect that when you are in the middle of the site and you move your mouse cursor towards the top of the viewport, the nav automatically slides down. You don't need to scroll, I believe it is detecting the location of your cursor with regards to the viewport.

Comment: i can't fire this effect without scroll button, you fire it with cursor on your demo website ?